# How to reliably implement disk space quotas in an application?

Tags: design, architecture

Suppose we have a service which allows users to store files on a disk. The service should keep track of disk space used by a user and enforce a limit on the available space. Google Drive or Dropbox are obvious examples of such services.

But furthermore suppose that size is tracked recursively for all of the user's directories. Effectively, such a service caches / pre-computes the result of `du` for all directories.

What are some good designs to keep track of disk usage per directory? I am especially interested in trade-offs involving atomicity and consistency.

Some ideas:

1. Keep the directory size in a dedicated, hidden file in that directory (e.g. `.__size__`). When adding / subtracting bytes from a directory, modify sizes of all parent directories as well. The downside of this would be a lack of atomicity if the application fails halfway through modifying parent directory sizes.
2. As a fix to aforementioned lack of atomicity and therefore possible inconsistencies, run a worker which traverses the directory tree, checking and fixing sizes. This would ensure eventual consistency.
3. Emit domain events when bytes are written / deleted, e.g. to a message broker, and process those events asynchronously to update sizes. This would ensure eventual consistency, but how would we ensure atomicity or idempotence on retries when processing such events?
4. Keep directory sizes in a relational database and update within a transaction.

Any thoughts?
3.

Comment: I'd expect the underlying file-system would likely have this information available directly - have you checked whether you can query it from there?

Comment: I would expect this to depend on the interface provided by the service for the users for accessing the storage, and how that is implemented using the underlying file system. Will there be one "root" folder per user in the file system used by the service? Moreover, what is your expectation about the behaviour when the quota limited is exceeded?

Comment: The best way I am sure would be to use the filesystem's own disk quota facilities. 'man quota' on a UNIX system. If a disk write passes the assigned quota it would fail and your application could then report thath the disk quota had been exceeded.

Comment: Thanks @JonGuiton , I wasn't aware of the `quota` utility.

Comment: @JonGuiton: correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't quota require "users" to be registered operating system users? From the question it seems to be pretty unclear if that is the kind of "users" the OP had in mind, or if the service manages its own user list (which is actually what I would expect). Piotr, can you please clarify?

Comment: @Doc Brown. You are correct, There would need to be some kind of pseudo user in order to use the facility. However quotas can be set up for individual projects `man edquota` and so the single pseudo user could manage 'user' quotas as projects.

Comment: I found this question https://serverfault.com/questions/100596/linux-quota-per-directory on serverfault, I guess that may contain what you are asking for.

Comment: That's right, I also saw the option of defining a quota per directory.